# OnTextChange / onchange JS event didnt fire in the inheritedpage from common user control

Tags: asp.net

I have one Common User control page called CommonDate.ascx  where it has a text box like below

`<asp:TextBox ID="ChangeValue" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>`

And the same is been registered in my web.config like

`<add tagPrefix="commonusercontrol" src="~/CUC/CommonDate.ascx" tagName="CommonDate"/>`

Now I ll use the above cuc in a different page "Home.ascx" like below

`<commonusercontrol:CommonDate ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" onchange="call()"/>`

The above onchage is a js event. Question is, Is it possible to call a onchange function or a ontextchanged function for the derived pages (from common user control). I tried to implement the above and failed to achieve.

Note: I have gone through all the questions in SO but none of them has the answer for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have JavaScript in that User Control.

The extra effort is to simply ensure that when you drop multiple controls on the web form that collisions in the JavaScript names don't occur.

Let's do a simple example. We will have a standard asp.net text box, but we will add a new setting/attribute called MaxLength. And then, as you type, below the text box, it will show/display the remaining characters. And when you reach the max character count, then the display of characters remaining will turn red color.

So, the above will require two things:

To assign a JavaScript routine to the `keydown` event of the text box.

To have each control on the web form work, and thus each web control calls their OWN JavaScript routine that keeps track of the characters typed in. And thus, that JavaScript code has to run/work correctly against that given text box ID.

I'm going to assume jQuery here.

So, first, our user control markup:

Keep in mind one would normally attempt to use/inject sever side expressions into the text box markup. However, since the text box control IS ALREADY a server-side control, then we can't use server-side expressions in the markup. (this applies to most controls).

So, I REALLY wanted the text box to be written this way:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyLimitbox" runat="server"
    textmode="MultiLine" 
    Height="153px" Width="445px"
    onkeyup='fc<%=Me.ID%>'
    >
</asp:TextBox>
```

So, I want the JavaScript routine for `onkeyup` to be set to the id of the control, (or at least something similar). We need to support multiple instances of that control being dropped into the web form.

So, we have to move the above server-side expression to the on-load event of the user control.

So, we now have markup:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="MyLimitbox" runat="server"
        textmode="MultiLine" 
        Height="153px" Width="445px"
        >
    </asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblRemain" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>



<script>


    function fc<%=Me.id%>(tbox) {

        var charsmax = <%= Me.MaxChars %>
        var charsLeft = (charsmax - $(tbox).val().length)
        var dbox = $('#<%=Me.lblRemain.ClientID%>')
        dbox.text(charsLeft + " / " + charsmax)
        if (charsLeft < 0) {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightCoral')
        }
        else {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightBlue')
        }
    }


</script>
```

So, note how we name the JavaScript routine based on the ID of the control. I tend to use "uc" (user control) for variables, some var name, and THEN followed by the control ID so we can have multiple instances of the control on the page.

And for the function names, then I prefix with "fc" (function control).

And for code behind, we have this:

```
    Dim m_MaxCars As Integer = 150

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.MyLimitbox.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", $"fc{Me.ClientID}(this);")

    End Sub


    Public Property MaxChars As Integer
        Get
            Return m_MaxCars
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_MaxCars = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return Me.MyLimitbox.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.MyLimitbox.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

As I stated, note how we moved sever side expression "onkeyup" to the load even of the control.

So, now let’s create a test page with the above. Our testing page of course will include jQuery, since I did use some jQuery in above markup.

So, our test page code looks like this:

```
    <div style="padding:35px">

        <uc1:LimitBox runat="server" ID="LimitBox"
            MaxChars="100"
            />

    </div>
```

Of course when we dragged the UC into the markup, then VS will add the directive near the top of the page.

e.g.:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/LimitBox.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="LimitBox" %>
```

So, running our test page, we get this:

```
    <div style="padding:35px">

        <textarea name="LimitBox$MyLimitbox" rows="2" cols="20"
          id="LimitBox_MyLimitbox" 
          onkeyup="fcLimitBox(this);" 
          style="height:153px;width:445px;">
        </textarea>
<br />

<span id="LimitBox_lblRemain"></span>



<script>


    function fcLimitBox(tbox) {

        var charsmax = 100
        var charsLeft = (charsmax - $(tbox).val().length)
        var dbox = $('#LimitBox_lblRemain')
        dbox.text(charsLeft + " / " + charsmax)
        if (charsLeft < 0) {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightCoral')
        }
        else {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightBlue')
        }
    }


</script>
```

So, the above markup generated by .net is not really all that important to view and read, but it DOES show how we used the "id" of the control to create a function name based on that control id.

This allows one to drop in 1, or 5 or whatever how many copies of the user control into that web page, and each will have its own JavaScript routine with its own variables and code that applies to the one control.

So, if I drop in 2 controls like this:

```
        <uc1:LimitBox runat="server" ID="LimitBox"
            MaxChars="100"
            />
        <br />
        <uc1:LimitBox runat="server" ID="Zoo"
            MaxChars="100"
            />

    </div>
```

Then note how the 2nd control with id="Zoo" results in this JavaScript code:

```
 <span id="Zoo_lblRemain"></span>

    function fcZoo(tbox) {

        var charsmax = 100
        var charsLeft = (charsmax - $(tbox).val().length)
        var dbox = $('#Zoo_lblRemain')
        dbox.text(charsLeft + " / " + charsmax)
        if (charsLeft < 0) {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightCoral')
        }
        else {
            dbox.css('background-color', 'LightBlue')
        }
    }
```

So, as you can see, the label, the text box, and the JavaScript all receive a custom name based on the control id for each instance of the control.

F5 to run, and we get this:

[image]

Of course, we probably would add to the above JavaScript routine to kill (discard) any keys pressed after 100 chars (or whatever setting we used). However, the key concepts outlined above shows how the user control can have custom JavaScript code, and can have custom values and variables that apply to the one control in question (in this example a standard text box control).

You don't note/mention if your "call()" is to be some general JavaScript, or a custom routine of JavaScript code for each given control, and each having some JavaScript based on the control ID.

If your example was ONLY that "call()" was not working, then you have to provide more markup. And in the use case of multiple user controls on a given page, but they all can use/share the SAME JavaScript routines? Then I suggest that you do NOT include such JavaScript with each control but require a href to the JavaScript routines. In other words, only place the custom JavaScript routines and functions that belong to the user control in the markup for that control. This most certainly means that in some cases multiple copies of some routines will exist on the one page (based on control ID). However, such code for a control tends to be short JavaScript routines, and they can of course can share general JavaScript routines anyway.

Just keep in mind that server side controls don't allow the <%=%> expressions, so you have to use the page load event of the user control to set the `onkey`, or `onchange` or whatever for the server side control.

In your case, the `onchange` client side settings should be placed in the user control markup section, and not in the user control as you have. You certainly could add a public property to the user control that allows setting of the client side JavaScript code routine.

So, in your example, you have this:

```
<commonusercontrol:CommonDate ID="NameTextBox" 
   runat="server" 
   onchange="call()"/>
```

So, we add to the above user control this public property

```
Public Property OnChange As String
    Get
        Return MyLimitbox.Attributes("onchange")
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        MyLimitbox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "value")
    End Set
End Property
```

And now in our test page, let's use this new feature in the 2nd user control example.

Hence, this markup:

```
        <uc1:LimitBox runat="server" ID="Zoo"
            MaxChars="50"
            OnChange="mycooljava()"
            />

        <script>
            function mycooljava() {
                alert("you changed the box")
            }
        </script>
```

And result is this:

[image]

So, it not really clear if you just wanted a custom routine to be called for the user control, and you place that custom JavaScript and attribute in the user control (my first example).

Or, you need/want the second example in which you are freely able to specify a custom attribute such as `onchange` to the user control, and have it call a client side JavaScript routine of your choice that exists in the same webform page as the user control been dropped into (the second example).

Comment: Thank you for the broader explanation. This helps me..

Comment: Note how we exposed the .text property and onchange property of the textbox by defined public properties of the uc. It was not really clear if the js called was to exist in uc markup or in target page markup.  So I gave example of both cases. And introducing part of uc "id" into js function name used shows how each uc can have/enjoy it's own js function code for each copy of a uc dropped into a web page. Looking closely it seems you wanted the 2nd case.